# ordering alpha numeric variable in r

Tags: r, sorting, alphanumeric

I would like to order a data frame based on an alphanumeric variable. Here how my dataset looks like:

```
sample.data <- data.frame(Grade=c(4,4,4,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
                          ItemID = c(15,15,15,15,17,17,17,17,16,16,16,16),
                          common.names = c("15_AS_SA1_Correct","15_AS_SA10_Correct","15_AS_SA2_Correct","15_AS_SA3_Correct",
                                            "17_AS_2_B2","17_AS_2_B1","17_AS_5_C1","17_AS_4_D1",
                                           "16_AS_SA1_Negative","16_AS_SA11_Prediction","16_AS_SA12_UnitMeaning","16_AS_SA3_Complete"))

> sample.data
   Grade ItemID           common.names
1      4     15      15_AS_SA1_Correct
2      4     15     15_AS_SA10_Correct
3      4     15      15_AS_SA2_Correct
4      4     15      15_AS_SA3_Correct
5      3     17             17_AS_2_B2
6      3     17             17_AS_2_B1
7      3     17             17_AS_5_C1
8      3     17             17_AS_4_D1
9      3     16     16_AS_SA1_Negative
10     3     16  16_AS_SA11_Prediction
11     3     16 16_AS_SA12_UnitMeaning
12     3     16     16_AS_SA3_Complete
```

I need to order by `Grade` and `ItemID`, then by `common.names` variable that contains alphanumeric.

I used this:

```
sample.data.ordered <- sample.data %>%
  arrange(Grade, ItemID,common.names)
```

but it did not work for the whole set.

My desired output is:

```
> sample.data.ordered
   Grade ItemID           common.names
1      3     16     16_AS_SA1_Negative
2      3     16     16_AS_SA3_Complete
3      3     16  16_AS_SA11_Prediction
4      3     16 16_AS_SA12_UnitMeaning
5      3     17             17_AS_2_B1
6      3     17             17_AS_2_B2
7      3     17             17_AS_4_D1
8      3     17             17_AS_5_C1
9      4     15      15_AS_SA1_Correct
10     4     15      15_AS_SA2_Correct
11     4     15      15_AS_SA3_Correct
12     4     15     15_AS_SA10_Correct
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Comment: In your sample data it looks like `17` is associated with `16_AS_SA1_Negative` and `16`  is associated with `17_AS_2_B2`. Are you trying to reorder the rows or sort each column independently?

Comment: You are right, sorry, I corrected it now. Could you please check now? Thanks for your careful eye!

Comment: I was going to suggest `gtools::mixedorder()`, but it's not flexible enough for this case ...although it might work in conjunction with `separate()`...

Comment: Ia actually tried `gtools::mixedorder()` but that did not provide the intended results. THanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `base R` solution using `order` as well as a more complex procedure for `common.names` involving `gsub`, regular expression and multiple backreference to match the numbers in the strings by which the column can be ordered:

```
sample.data[order(sample.data$Grade, 
              sample.data$ItemID, 
              as.numeric(gsub(".*(SA|AS_)(\\d+)_(\\w)?(\\d)?.*", "\\2\\4", sample.data$common.names))),]
   Grade ItemID           common.names
9      3     16     16_AS_SA1_Negative
12     3     16     16_AS_SA3_Complete
10     3     16  16_AS_SA11_Prediction
11     3     16 16_AS_SA12_UnitMeaning
6      3     17             17_AS_2_B1
5      3     17             17_AS_2_B2
8      3     17             17_AS_4_D1
7      3     17             17_AS_5_C1
1      4     15      15_AS_SA1_Correct
3      4     15      15_AS_SA2_Correct
4      4     15      15_AS_SA3_Correct
2      4     15     15_AS_SA10_Correct
```

Comment: the `common.names` variable also needs to be ordered. The order should start as `"16_AS_SA1_Negative","16_AS_SA3_Complete","16_AS_SA11_Prediction","16_AS_SA12_UnitMeaning"`....

Comment: your order is still the same. Somehow `R` wants to order it as `SA_1, SA_11, SA_12, then SA_3` but I want to have `SA_1, SA_3, SA_11, SA_12`

Comment: How about this new edited solution? Does that work for you?

Comment: can we do one more round for `G=17`, the order is supposed to be `"17_AS_2_B1","17_AS_2_B2","17_AS_4_D1","17_AS_5_C1"`

Comment: Again made an edit. Now the output seems to match your desired output exactly. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks, @Chris for your time and effort.